# Install Anaconda in a specific location

Tags: python, configuration, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm wondering how to go about installing Anaconda `miniconda` in a particular location on my system.

If I have some project

```
~/some-project
```

That I want to use `conda` for, but don't want to use `conda` anywhere else on my system, how do I go about that?

Ideally there will be some approach where I can do

```
cd ~/some-project
install miniconda here only as some-project-env
```

And I can then, within `~/some-project`, activate `some-project-env`. This solution will not touch any `rc` configuration files, all configuration settings for `some-project-env` will be contained within `~/some-project`.

So, if I was to only create `some-project-env`, and then deleted `~/some-project`, there would be no trace of `conda` on my system.

## Edit

It would still be of interest to have a solution to this post. Something that might be of use to someone finding this is the following in their `~/.condarc`

```
auto_activate_base: false
```

Comment: Just install Miniconda in default location and set the configuration option `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` to avoid Conda being used by default. Then create a new environment just for use with your project. There is a `--prefix` flag to specify an env location, but I wouldn't try to associate a specific folder for the env with the project. Instead, let it go in the default location and activate it by name when working on the project.

Comment: @merv will this lead to my `rc` file being polluted by conda? Ideally, I would like to have this completely contained within the project folder as stated in the question. However, if it's possible to have something that doesn't interfere with config files and that is simple to use, I could edit the question accordingly. I will consider what you've written, thanks

Comment: You're right, what I've suggested will still add to your `rc` and doesn't satisfy the requirements you've specified. This is why I only gave it as a comment, not an answer. I want to raise the alternative perspective that you can still install Conda globally without it being active by default or having to use it as a default package manager.

Comment: Can't you choose the install location when setting up Miniconda?

Comment: @AMC such that _all_ config settings are placed within the selected location? I don't think so, or at least, I haven't found such a setting. I believe that you can store the distribution in some `~/baz`, but there will still be settings placed in `rc` files etc bytes  conda.